# List members from nested Azure AD group

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have an Azure AD Group, "All-Team". That inturn has three groups:

1. SrMgr_E3
2. directs
3. Sachbearbeiter

Each group has a list of members and I want to fetch members from the groups.

The below command gives me list of groups, but I want it to give a list of members from all the group. I was assuming that Azure AD was a FLAT structure and it would list out all the members from the group (nested including).

```
$group_objectid = (Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString 'All-Team').objectid
Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group_objectid
```

The above command will give me list of three groups, but I want the list of all the members from that group. Is there a command that does that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such command, the `list members` operation is not transitive, your option is to use a loop:

```
$group_objectid = (Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString 'joytestg').ObjectId
$group2_objectid = (Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group_objectid).ObjectId
foreach($item in $group2_objectid){
    Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $item
}
```